# php change value from file to another file

Tags: php, file, fopen, fgets

I have 2 files (A.txt and B.txt). 
I want to change / update file B of information on file A. 
the contents of the file A is :

```
Fish    2   4
Horse   3   2
Chicken 1   5
```

the contents of the file B is :

```
not 5   2
not 3   2
not 2   2
not 2   4
```

I want to get his results from file B, like this:

```
not 5   2
Horse   3   2
not 2   2
Fish    2   4
```

I know it use the expression "if". but I do not know how to code. is there anything that can help? in the file are separated by the "tabs" and "newline"

Comment: What happened to `Chicken 1   5` ?

Comment: ignored, because in a file no [link](1 15)

Comment: It still doesn't make sense.. Can you explain how are you arriving at the results ??

Comment: I just answered you,, see whether this will help you

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<?php

    foreach (file("A.txt") as $line) 
    {
        // Split line
        $field = preg_split('/\s+/',$line);

        // This is your array index
        $index = $field[1].' '.$field[2];

        // Array holds name which is first field
        $Array[$index] = $field[0];
    }

    foreach(file("B.txt") as $line)
    {

        // Split field   
        $field = preg_split('/\s+/',$line);

        // 2nd file index
        $index = $field[1].' '.$field[2];

        // if index is set in array echo name else line
        echo (isset($Array[$index])?$Array[$index].' '.$index:$line).'<br>';
    }
?>
```

Would result for given input

```
 not 5 2
 Horse 3 2
 not 2 2
 Fish 2 4
```